# An explanation of the definition of the characteristic function of the bivariate stable distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, definition, bivariate-distributions

The multivariate stable distribution is defined as follows (see Nolan 2013 or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_stable_distribution#Definition)). Let $\mathbb{S}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^d\colon \mathbb{S} = \{u \in \mathbb R^d\colon|u| = 1\}$. A random vector $X$ has a multivariate stable distribution, that is $X \sim S(\alpha, \Lambda, \delta)$, if the joint characteristic function of $X$ is:

$$\operatorname{E} \exp(i u^T X) = \exp \left\{-\int \limits_{s \in \mathbb S}\left\{|u^Ts|^\alpha + i \nu (u^Ts, \alpha) \right\} \, \Lambda(ds) + i u^T\delta\right\}$$

For $y\in\mathbb R$,

$$\nu(y,\alpha) =\begin{cases} -\mathbf{sign}(y) \tan(\pi \alpha / 2)|y|^\alpha & \alpha \ne 1, \\
(2/\pi)y \ln |y| & \alpha=1. \end{cases}$$

$\delta \in \mathbb R^d$ is the shift parameter and $\Lambda$ is a spectral measure of the distribution. $0<\alpha<2$ is the stability parameter.

My question is this. Could someone please explain to me (in simple, intuitive terms) what $u$ is? It appears throughout the first equation, but I don't know what it is. What is its relationship with $s$?

*Nolan, John P.*, [**Multivariate elliptically contoured stable distributions: theory and estimation**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00180-013-0396-7), Comput. Stat. 28, No. 5, 2067-2089 (2013). [ZBL1306.65118](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1306.65118).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me make an analogy to a characteristic function of a real valued random variable.

Given a random variable $X$, its characteristic function is the map $\varphi_X \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined as:

$$ \varphi_X(u) \, \colon = \mathbf{E} \left[ e^{ i u X} \right].$$

Note that since the expectation is taken over the variable $X$, this becomes a function of $u$ only. Characteristic functions are useful, since if you have two random variables $X, \, Y$ and you can show that

$$\varphi_X(u) = \varphi_Y(u), \qquad \forall \, x,\,y \, \in \mathbb{R}$$

then it follows that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution.

Now returning back to your context: in your case the variable does not take values in $\mathbb{R}$, but rather in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The equivalent form of a characteristic function for a variable $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a function $\varphi_X \colon \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where now:

$$\varphi_X( u) \, \colon = \mathbf{E} \left[ e^{i u^T X} \right],$$

note that we can take the expectation as $u^T X = \sum_{i=1}^d u_i X_i \in \mathbb{R}$ (since expectations only make sense for `1-dimensional' variables).

As in the case of $d = 1$, if you can show that given two variables $X, Y$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that

$$\varphi_X(u) = \varphi_Y(u), \qquad \forall \, x, \, y \in \mathbb{R}^d$$

then it follows that the variables are equal in distribution.

**Further Introduction to Characteristic Functions**

In this I go into some more detail to motivate characteristic functions. I return to the scenario that $X$ is a real valued variable, and $\varphi_X \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

A common question in probability / statistics is: given two random variables / sets of data, how do I know if they have the same distribution.

A first approach might be to check: do they have the same expectation (mean, if doing statistics)? So suppose we have variables $X, Y$ we might say

$$ \text{Is } \mathbf{E}[X] = \mathbf{E}[Y] \text{ true?}$$

If its not then we'd conclude that they're definitely do not have the same distribution.

But, is the converse true? If $X, \, Y$ have the same mean, do they have the same distribution? The answer is no.

**Example**

Suppose $X \sim N(0,1)$ (a normal distribution with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$), and $Y \sim \text{Unif}[-1,1]$ (a uniform variable on the interval $[-1,1]$). Both variables have the property

$$ \mathbf{E}[X] = \mathbf{E}[Y] = 0$$

However they definitely don't have the same distribution (since $\mathbf{P}[X > 1] > 0$, whilst $\mathbf{P}[Y > 1] = 0$).

So we might then ask: "If two random variables have the same mean, and the same variance... Do they have the same distribution?". Again the answer to this is no.

**Example**

Suppose $X \sim N(1,1)$ and $Y \sim \text{Poi}(1)$ (a Poisson variable with mean $1$). Then

$$\mathbf{E}[X] = \mathbf{E}[Y] = 1, \qquad \text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(Y) = 1$$

Similarly we can construct examples for any given integer $k \geq 0$ that show that

$$\mathbf{E}[ X^k] = \mathbf{E}[Y^k]$$

and yet $X$ and $Y$ do not have the same distribution. We call $\mathbf{E}[X^k]$ the $k-$th moment of $X$.

However... It turns out (and this requires proving) that if you can show that all moments of the distributions agree: then they have the same distribution. i.e. if

$$\mathbf{E}[X^k] = \mathbf{E}[Y^k], \qquad \forall \, k \geq 0$$

then $X \sim Y$.

How does this relate to the characteristic function?

A similar statement from real analysis says that a power series uniquely determines a function. So the insight is: if we create a power series with the moments of $X$ as coefficients, and then we find a variable $Y$ with the same power series... Then: uniqueness of power series implies they have the same coefficients, i.e. the same moments, and therefore have the same distribution!

So we construct the power series:

$$ f(u) = \mathbf{E}[X^0] + \mathbf{E}[X^1] u + \mathbf{E}[X^2] \frac{u^2}{2!} + \mathbf{E}[X^3] \frac{u^3}{3!} + \cdots$$

We introduce the parameter $u$ purely as an artificial way to make a function from a sequence of moments $\{\mathbf{E}[X^k]\}_{k \geq 0}$. Using linearity of expectations, and the convenience of dividing the moments by factorials,we get:

$$ f(u) = \mathbf{E}\left[ 1 + uX + \frac{u^2X^2}{2}+ \frac{u^3X^3}{3!} + \cdots \right] = \mathbf{E}[ e^{uX} ]$$

The function $f$ is almost the characteristic function (its missing the $i$), and is known as the moment generating function. The above argument therefore says that if we have two random variables $X,Y$ and they have the same moment generating function, then they have the same distribution.

Introduction of the parameter $i$, so $f(iu)$, changes very little: the claim is still true that $\varphi = f(iu)$ uniquely determines the distribution. Really the addition of $i$ is historic, in as much as $\varphi$ is equivalent to the Fourier transform in real analysis.

So in short: the moments of a random variable uniquely determine the distribution. Therefore, a power series with the moments as coefficients uniquely determines the distribution. The characteristic function is exactly that: a power series, in some parameter $u$, with the moments of a random variable as coefficients.

The value of $u$ itself is not of interest: $u$ is a way to encode a sequence of information (the coefficients), as a function over a continuous parameter.

Comment: Many thanks. Apologies for not voting up your answer, I lack reputation! I'm still confused about something though. I feel like I'm missing some  very obvious and / or very fundamental idea. Your second equation highlights my confusion. In the statement  $\varphi_X(u) = \varphi_Y(u)$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, what is $u$?? I understand when talking about x or y as observations from X and Y, but how does this $u$ enter the picture?

Comment: Hi, I've added a (rather lengthy!) introduction to characteristic functions. Hopefully this might help you understand the motivation for them. Let me know if anything is still unclear!

Comment: Wow OK, interesting! That cleared up a lot! Thank you very much!! :-)